# Xcode project, app name, best practice

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the best way to specify the name of the app?

I'm aware of doing it in three different ways:

1. Target -> Build Settings -> Product name
2. Info.plist -> Bundle name
3. Use localization -> InfoPlist.strings -> "CFBundleDisplayName" and
   "CFBundleName"

I think it is best to use the third option, but not totally sure. Please share your opinions and experience on what's best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Project name is different to the app name I personally always change it via the Info.plist

Changing the `Bundle Name` allows the name of the app on the device to be what you want which is helpful when your project name is long but you want a short app name on the device

*EDIT - Photo added for reference*

You would just change the text in there :)

[image]

Comment: The content of the spaces in "Product Name" can break something in the project?

Answer (score 0):

> You should set the "CFBundleDisplayName" in the Info.plist file for the app name.

It's the best place I have found of to use the application name.

Other than that, the other two options work fine just well too. It's a matter of personal preference only.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari